# Defining a new word within frequency analysis

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to know how to define a new word which can include others. For example:

```
Word    Frequency
0   game    52055
1   laura   24953
2   luke    21133
3   story   20739
4   dog     17054
35  cat     4244
```

I would like to 'create' a new word, `pet`, which include `dog` and `cat` and their corresponding frequency. Something like this:

```
Word    Frequency
0   game    52055
1   Laura   24953
4   pet     21298
2   luke    21133
3   story   20739
```

I am thinking of using a dictionary to do it:

```
thisdict = {
  "dog": "pet",
  "cat": "pet"}
```

but I am not sure on how to apply it and if this can allow me to keep also their values (21298 in total)

Comment: `df.groupby(df['Word'].map(thisdict)).sum()` would suffice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`replace` first then do `groupby`

```
df.Word.replace(thisdict,inplace=True)
df
Out[104]: 
     Word  Frequency
0    game      52055
1   laura      24953
2    luke      21133
3   story      20739
4     pet      17054
35    pet       4244
df = df.groupby(['Word'], as_index=False).sum()
df
Out[106]: 
    Word  Frequency
0   game      52055
1  laura      24953
2   luke      21133
3    pet      21298
4  story      20739
```